# Dataframe change column value on if statement and keeps the new value to next row

Tags: dataframe

I wish you good health to you and your family.

In my dataframe  I have a column 'condition' which is filled with .astype(float).

Based on information that i put in this dataframe for every row it makes math and if is over specific amount it increase the value of 'condition' by 1 . Everything works fine with it and as it should be.

I made another column named ['order']. Which change its value if ['condition'] has value of 3. That's the code with witch you can see what I mean:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def graph():
             df = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-3,4,size=(100, 1)), columns=[('condition')]))
             df['order'] = 0 
             df.loc[(df['condition'] == 3) & (df['order'] == 0) , 'order'] = df['order'] + 1 
             df.loc[(df['condition'] == -3) & (df['order'] == 1) , 'order'] = df['order'] + -1
             df.to_csv('copy_bars.csv') 

graph()
```

As you can see it changes the value in 'order' row to 1 when it fill first condition. But it never change back from 1 to 0 because of second if statement. It changes to 0 just because at the begging I give the row amount of 0.

How could I modify the code so when it is changed to 1 to keep this new value until second if statement fill ?

```
Row, Condition, Order
0      -1           0
1       3           1
2      -1           0
3       2           0
4      -2           0
5      -3           0
6       0           0
```

instead of this I would like to get in Order column for line from 1 to 4 to be represented with value of 1 so can my second condition trigger.

Comment: can you share the actual code instead of what you remember? The code you wrote would not even run.

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu I did. Excuse me for late reply (I was on work)

Comment: Code seems to work but I don't completely understand what you want to accomplish. Would you like the all order values to equal 1 after condition 3 until the first -3? for every 3, -3 combination?

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu all order value to be 1 after first condition till second condition fills and if there is another 3 , -3 combination to do the same .

Comment: I believe this is simply easier to do with a for loop. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want this should be something like what you want. Because it is row by row and is based on two values it is not easy to vectorize but probably someone else can do it. Hope it works for you.

```
order = []
have_found_plus_3 = False

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    
    if row['condition'] == 3:
        have_found_plus_3 = True
    elif row['condition'] == -3:
        have_found_plus_3 = False
    if have_found_plus_3:
        order.append(1)
    else:
        order.append(0)
df['order'] = order
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: where? If you add it to the first if condition it will stop appending 1s immediately.

Comment: Instead of doing that you should just initialize have_found_plus_3 = False at the start of the program. If you do that you won't get an error if no 3 is found in the rows

Comment: and set it as global ?

Comment: It depends on your codebase but you should not need to if something is not terribly wrong :D

Comment: xD no ... not yet :D